# Problematic definition of empirical distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, definitions

Could you please me explain the definition of empirical distribution? In Wikipedia, the defining equality has a NUMBER on one side and a FUNCTION (the sum of functions) on the other, which seems a nonsense to me: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/aacca85bf28da15cbba66ea7c456cf7ad9784047

Comment: both sides of the equation are functions (of the real numbers $n$ and $t$)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: And of $\omega$...

Comment: I only see the number on the left – the value of the function F ^ _n at the point t and the function on a probability space (Meckes: "And of ω.."), on the right.

Comment: @Oto Rin: I think the formula in the wikipedia article is misleading. Originally the empirical distribution function has nothing to do with probability. For given data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ $\hat F_n(t)$ simply is the proportion of elements $x_i \leq t$. Of course you $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ may replaced by random values $X_1(\omega),\ldots,X_n(\omega)$. The investigation of the corresponding random variables then is part of (theoretical) statistics.

Answer (score 1):

What you see there (probably a better source is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)) is a formula defining, not the empirical distribution, but the empirical distribution function. The formula is this:
$$\hat F_n(t):=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{X_i\le t}, \tag{1}
$$ 
where $n$ is a natural number, $t$ is a real number, and $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent identically distributed real-valued random variables (r.v.'s). The condition on the $X_i$'s implies, in particular, that the $X_i$'s are real-valued functions on some set $\Omega$. So, formula (1) actually means this:
$$\hat F_n(t)(\omega):=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{X_i(\omega)\le t} \tag{1a}
$$
for all $\omega\in\Omega$; both sides of the equality in (1a) are real numbers.

For any given $n$ and $t$, $\hat F_n(t)=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{X_i\le t}$ is, not a real number, but a real-valued r.v., which is the function 
$$\Omega\ni\omega\mapsto\hat F_n(t)(\omega). 
$$
Thus, for any given $n$ and $t$, $\hat F_n(t)$ is a function only because $\hat F_n(t)$ is a r.v.

Also, for any given $n$, $\hat F_n$ (but of course not the r.v. $\hat F_n(t)$) may be considered a function from $\mathbb R$ to the set of all real-valued r.v.'s defined on the set $\Omega$; the value of this function at any point $t\in\mathbb R$ is the r.v. $\hat F_n(t)$.

Alternatively, for any given $n$, $\hat F_n$ may be considered a random function, that is, a (measurable in a certain sense) function from $\Omega$ to the set of all real-valued functions on $\mathbb R$. The value of this random function at any given point $\omega\in\Omega$ is the function
$$\mathbb R\ni t\mapsto \hat F_n(t)(\omega)=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{X_i(\omega)\le t}.
$$

Comment: To Iosif Pinelis.

Thank you for your answer. But if are values ​​of functions F^n(t) r.v., then the formulae in the paragraph Asymptotic properties do not make sense to me.

Asymptotic properties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function#Asymptotic_properties

Comment: @OroRin : First here, I did not say "are values ​​of functions F^n(t) r.v.". Instead, I said that $\hat F_n(t)$ is a r.v., for any given natural $n$ and real $t$. Second, why don't those asymptotic properties make sense to you? E.g., the statement    "$\hat F_n(t)$ converges to $F(t)$ as $n\to\infty$ almost surely" means, according to the standard definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition_3 , that $P(A_t)=1$, where $A_t:=\{\omega\in\Omega\colon \hat F_n(t)(\omega)\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow F(t)\}$, for each real $t$.

Comment: F^n(t) is r.v. (function on a probability space) and F(t) is a number (F is a distribution function). In "standard definition" are both Xn and X r.v.

Comment: As usual, the constant functions and, in particular, constant r.v.'s are identified with the corresponding constant values. E.g., we write $X=1$ meaning $X(\omega)=1$ for all $\omega$. So, "$X_n\to1$ almost surely" means that $X_n\to\mathbf1$ almost surely, where $\mathbf1$ is the constant r.v. defined by the formula $\mathbf1(\omega):=1$ for all $\omega$.

Comment: To Iosif Pinelis. Thank you for your patience. I'll think about Glivenko-Cantelli theorem again :-)